# Junit 5 extension - how to access testDescriptor

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I am writing an extension for a test using @ParameterizedTest. My test looks like:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings={"string1", "string2"})
public void test1(String name){
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

In the extensions, how do I get the TestDesciptor to find out which invocation in currently active?

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeEachCallBack{
   
 @Override
 public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext)   
     //  What to do here? extensionContext.?
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see by its package name `org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor` is not part of JUnit Jupiter API which has `org.junit.jupiter.api` as its base package. Moreover, `org.junit.platform.engine` is not even imported by the API.

So the sad answer is you cannot get at the test descriptor, at least not without some dirty and unstable reflection. I am, however, quite sure that the underlying reason you have for wanting access can be mitigated in a different way. So what is it you’d like to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The situation is:
I have 2 tests I need to implement. Each one has a unique id in Jira (Xray) - TestID1 and TestID2.
Both can be implemented in the same test method using @ParameterizedTest

However, I need to be aware which is currently running so I will be able to pair it with the correct Jira ticket.

This information is provided in the TestDescriptor object....

Any ideas?

Comment: You may try a TestExecutionListener: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom.  With it you have access to TestIdentifier and thereby the unique ID.

Comment: This is the better link: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom